# Vue doenst update modelValue inside watch

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-props

Emitting `update:modelValue` event inside $watch doesnt update modelValue if I dont pass modelValue by props. How I can make sure modelValue is updated without passing modelValue by props?

MyComponent:

```
export default defineComponent(
{
    template: '<div>{{modelValue}}</div>',
    props: 
    {
        modelValue: {type: Date},
        stringValue: {type: String},
    },
    emits: ['update:modelValue', 'update:stringValue'],
    mounted()
    {
        this.$watch(() => this.stringValue, (n, o) => 
        {
            let value = n == null ? null : moment(n, Format.NewMomentDate).toDate();
            
            this.$emit('update:modelValue', value);
        }, {immediate: true});
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<MyComponent v-model:string-value="ValidUntil">
</MyComponent>
```

Comment: I'm confused, what did you expect would happen?

Comment: modelValue supposed to be changed inside MyComponent and see changed modelValue in div

Comment: " if I dont pass modelValue by props" - what does it look like? `<MyComponent v-model:string-value="ValidUntil">`? update:modelValue affects nothing because there is no update:modelValue listener in a parent

Comment: my component template is this:  template: '<div>{{modelValue}}</div>' I expect this to be changed inside my component.

Answer (score 0):

I think this comes from a misunderstanding of how props work.

First of: props are (supposed to be treated as) read-only.

Vue doesn't have a two-way binding like AngularJS had. What it has is two one-way bindings: props and events.

`v-model`s are just a nicer syntax to work with that: it both binds a prop and and event listener.

The traditional flow is like this:

1. Bind the reactive data to `modelValue`
2. Bind the updater on `update:modelValue`
3. Trigger `update:modelValue`
4. The updater gets called and changes your reactive data
5. The prop value of `modelValue` gets changed and the component re-renders the changed parts

Here `update:modelValue` is triggered but since there's no listener for it, nothing will happen. Therefore, `modelValue` still has its default value: `undefined`.

Comment: Is there any way to setup some kind of default listener within my component so I would have to pass any props?

Comment: Nope. What you seem to want is to have a data member (or even a computed property) that you keep in sync with the other prop.